# puppet can't find pip : Parameter provider failed: Invalid package provider 'pip' at < path_to_pip_file >

Tags: pip, puppet

I have a simple .pp / puppet file, and I'm getting "Parameter provider failed: Invalid package provider 'pip' at sis.pp:24"

Here's the line 24:

```
 20 package {"numpy":
 21                 ensure => installed,
 22                 provider => pip,
 23                 require => Package["python-setuptools", "python-pip", "python-dev", "build-essential"]
 24         }
```

I checked for syntax errors, there are none.

My guess is that puppet can't find pip, I uninstalled and installed pip again. With apt-get,
here's what i get when i type "whereis pip"

```
pip: /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/share/man/man1/pip.1.gz
```

I searched around and found that puppet has a pip module, installed it too.

But still clueless about what the problem is.

When I type "puppet apply sis.pp --debug --verbose"

I get this:

```
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderSunfreeware: file pkg-get does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderFink: file /sw/bin/fink does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderYum: file yum does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderRug: file /usr/bin/rug does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderAix: file /usr/bin/lslpp does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderPorts: file /usr/sbin/pkg_info does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderNim: file /usr/sbin/nimclient does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderRpm: file rpm does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderSun: file /usr/sbin/pkgrm does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderPortupgrade: file /usr/sbin/pkg_info does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderHpux: file /usr/sbin/swremove does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderZypper: file /usr/bin/zypper does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderFreebsd: file /usr/sbin/pkg_delete does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderUp2date: file /usr/sbin/up2date-nox does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderPkg: file /usr/bin/pkg does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderPortage: file /usr/bin/eix does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderAptrpm: file rpm does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderOpenbsd: file pkg_delete does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderUrpmi: file urpmq does not exist
Parameter provider failed: Invalid package provider 'pip' at /path/sis.pp:54
```

Observe the puppet interpreter is pointing to multiple places in the sis.pp file where it couldn't process provider => "pip"

need help. I'm now going to try and find the terminal output code lines in puppet source to see what the problem is. If somebody knows the solution already, help would be appreciated.

I'm on ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your installation can't find the pip provider, rather than it not being able to find the pip executable.

I'm guessing the provider you mentioned is this one:

https://github.com/rcrowley/puppet-pip

Couple of things that might not be clear:

1. The plugin needs to be available on the puppet clients
2. Just installing the Gem won't do it for you, hence the manual env setting in the README

Probably the easiest approach is to include the puppet-pip provider in your puppet repo as a separate module, and then enable pluginsync, i.e.

```
[main]
pluginsync = true
```

More details here http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/plugins_in_modules.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like pip provider is not available in puppet pre 2.7 without downloading an external provider.  Are you using 2.7 or higher?